# UndefinedError: 'url_for' is undefined; while using Jinja2 in Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm trying to use Jinja2 templating language with Django. While trying to render a template I got the error "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'url_for' is undefined". 'url_for()' works absolutely fine when used with templates in Flask Applications.

The template looks like this:

```html
{% extends "login_auth/base.html" %}
{% block title %} ProjectName {% endblock %}
{% block style %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index_stl.css')}}">    
    <script src="{{ url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The Traceback is as follows:

```py
File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/ProjectName/login_auth/views.py" in index
  10.     return render(request,"login_auth/index.html")  # index.html will be welcome screen

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/jinja2.py" in render
  71.         return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py" in render
  76.             return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py" in render
  1008.         return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py" in handle_exception
  780.         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py" in reraise
  37.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/ProjectName/login_auth/jinja2/login_auth/index.html" in top-level template folder2
  1. {% extends "login_auth/base.html" %}

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/ProjectName/login_auth/jinja2/login_auth/base.html" in top-level template folder2
  12.         {% block style %} {% endblock %}    

File "/home/ParserMouth/folder1/folder2/ProjectName/ProjectName/login_auth/jinja2/login_auth/index.html" in block "style"
  4.     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index_stl.css') }}">

Exception Type: UndefinedError at /
Exception Value: 'url_for' is undefined
```

I want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VoteCoffee sir this question is specific to django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out answer for my question. The problem occurred because 'url_for' function is provided by Flask and not Jinja2. So You need to do a little bit of configuration to load static files in your templates.
1. Add jinja2.py in Project's default app and add following code in it:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reversefrom jinja2 import Environmentdef environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        ‘static’: staticfiles_storage.url,
        ‘url’: reverse,
    })
 return env
```

2. After this you need to replace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index_stl.css')}}">    
<script src="{{ url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
```

with this:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href="{{ static('login_auth/index.css') }}">
<script src="{{ static('login_auth/index.js') }}"></script>
```

Reference:[Using Jinja2 with Django](https://medium.com/@samuh/using-jinja2-with-django-1-8-onwards-9c58fe1204dc)

Comment: im facing same error on flask while rendering jinja2. it gives url_for undefined. any idea about flask?

Comment: @Harley check whether you are importing static files and have jinja2 configured properly in your virtualenv. As far as I can say you should not face this issue as you're using flask and not django.

Comment: @AzamAbbasi hopefully you have found the answer by now but in case someone is looking for flask version then, while rendering the template you can pass url_for of flask.
e.g. `env.get_template('xyz.html').render(url_for=url_for)`

Answer (score 1):

i think you have imported

```
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.loaders import FileSystemLoader
```

font-end if looking for `{{ url_for() }}` in `jinja2` where it is not available

try to resolve it using back-end logic like:

```
csslink = url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index_stl.css')
jslink = url_for('static/login_auth', filename='index.js')

return tmpl.render(csslink = csslink, jslink = jslink )
```

and on front-end

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ csslink }}">    
<script src="{{ jslink }}"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for the URL filter

if you have this in your urls :

```
path('client/<int:id>/', app_views.client, name='app-views-client')
```

you can call it this way :

```
{% url 'app-views-client' client.id %}
```

info : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Sir, as I have mentioned in my question I'm using Jinja2 templating in my project, not django's default template. I'm using "url_for" to load my static file in my template and not trying to link to get url for a view in django app.

Comment: my bad ! 
Can you try something similar to this :
{{url(‘app-views-client’, args=[client.id])}}
or 
{{url('app-views-client', kwargs={'id':client.id}}}

Comment: Ya sure. I'll try and revert back.